# Return Web API headers earlier

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way, when using ASP.NET Web API, to return the response headers earlier?

An example:
Let's say I have an action in my controller which returns all companies for a filter

```
    // GET api/companies/filter
    public Companies Get(string someFilter)
    {
        // some long operation (10 seconds)
    }
```

I would like to return the headers ASAP and while doing that, the long operation should take place, and then return the data of the long operation.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: So you want to return 2 seperate HTTP responses?

Comment: Could you give more details as to what is your exact scenario and why is that you would want to send the response headers asap? Let's say if the headers are sent back as 200 OK and in midst of completing writing the response if an error happens..do you plan to handle it at the client?

Comment: This way the client knows that he was able to access the server, that the server is currently working and that he will receive a response from it soon. And I can then use on the client side : await httpClient.GetAsync(address, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, myTokenWithATimeoutForHeaders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use PushStreamContent to do this

```
// GET api/companies/filter
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string someFilter)
{
    // some long operation (10 seconds)

    var pushContent = new PushStreamContent( (stream, content, ctx) =>
        {
            // Do long running thing here, writing to stream
        });


   return new HttpResponseMessage() {
      Content = pushContent
   }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Darell. I will be able to perform what I want using it.